# How many ways to get the terms of sequence 1-100 sum up to 9?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations, problem-solving

I stumbled upon this in a binomial expansion problem where I was supposed to find the coefficient of $x^9$ in $$\prod_{i=1}^{100}{(1+x^i)}$$
The problem is simple enough, all I need to do is to find the coefficient of $x^9$ in the factors up till $(1+x^9)$, which I did through mindless labour by finding out all the possible singlets, pairs and triplets, but I'm not satisfied with it.

**Isn't there a better, more subtle way to approach this?** One thing that comes to my mind is using the number of integral solutions of:
$$x_1=9\\ x_1+x_2=9\\ x_1+x_2+x_3=9$$

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) and search "partitions into distinct parts" there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You are looking for the number of partitions of $9$ into distinct parts, and since $1+2+3+4=10>9$ there only are partitions with $1,2$ or $3$ parts. There obviously are four partitions with two parts and a single partition with one part. Counting the solutions of 
$$ a+b+c = 9 $$
with $a>b>c>0$ is the same as counting the solutions of 
$$ (C+B+A)+(C+B)+C = 9\quad \text{or}\quad  3C+2B+A=9$$
with $A,B,C\in\mathbb{N}^+$. $2B+A=6$ has $2$ solutions and $2B+A=3$ has $1$ solution, hence

$$ [x^9]\prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1+x^k\right) = 4+1+2+1 = \color{red}{8}.$$

Comment: This is the first time I'm approaching this topic, that is, solutions of a+b+c =k, such that a>b>c. Could you please refer some articles to me for reading so that I'm able to fully understand it. I really loved the solution by the way. :)

Comment: @UtkarshVerma: it's actually a pretty standard substitution: $b>c$ means $b=c+\tau$ with $\tau>0$, hence we set $C=c$ and $b=C+B$.

Comment: Thanks. I've understood it.